# Why I am not getting empty field of type external Id, while fetching if from soql query?

Tags: apex, soql, community, externalid

Fetch empty text value of type external id using SOQL query in apex. I am using this query :

```
Select id,name,CommentBody__c,CommentId__c,ParentId__c 
from Case_Comment__c 
where ParentId__c =:caseObj.id
```

Where CommentId__c is external id type field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking those values in the debug or creating a JSON then those null values will be ignored.

You can create a wrapper to check those null values in the apex or can even use the null check.